# jquery click() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem with jQuery click() function.

I use this function to programatically click on a link which calls an ajax function that adds a new object to the database.

When I submit my form, a tr is added in the object datatable for my new object with new link and I want to programatically click on this new link to load object properties and display them.

The problem is that the new tr with td and link doesn't exist in DOM and the function `$.('#elem').click')` doesn't work.

I saw in others post that I have to bind click event with the new .on function like this :

```
$('#parent-items').on('click', 'elem', function() {
   // [...]
});
```

I don't know what I have to write in place of [...], at the end of my javascript code, I call the click function like this :

```
$('#myelem').click();
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `elem` is not an element, its an id

Comment: replace `[...]` with `alert("hi there")`. Then you'll be able to see if your call to `$('#myelem').click()` is working. Once you're sure it is, then replace the alert with a call to your ajax function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that hard, actually. :)

```
<table id="list">
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td><a class="btn-hi">Say Hi!</a></td>
        <td><a class="btn-bye">Say Goodbye!</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lucy</td>
        <td><a class="btn-hi">Say Hi!</a></td>
        <td><a class="btn-bye">Say Goodbye!</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sam</td>
        <td><a class="btn-hi">Say Hi!</a></td>
        <td><a class="btn-bye">Say Goodbye!</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
$('#list').on('click', 'a', function() {
    // Wrap the clicked <a> element with jQuery
    var $this = $(this);

    // Get the parent <tr> element
    var $tr = $this.closest('tr');

    // Get all (direct) children elements (<td>) that are inside the current <tr> element
    var $tds = $tr.children();

    // Get the text from the first <td> element in the current row
    var name = $tds.eq(0).text();

    // Get the type (class name) of clicked link
    var type = $this.attr('class');

    if (type == 'btn-hi') {
            alert( 'Hi, ' + name + '!' );
    } else if (type == 'btn-bye') {
            alert( 'Goodbye, ' + name + '!' );
    }
});
</script>
```

Have a look at this demo in JSBin: http://jsbin.com/welcome/38776/edit

The click event will get executed every time when user clicks on any `<a>` element that is inside `<table id="list">` element. It's called "event delegation" - http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

So, you can dynamically add more rows to the table and everything will still work.

Comment: That is a good demonstration, but you should probably use his selectors.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I wanted to call ajax function directly by call the click function (I do that with existing DOM elements) rather than call ajax with success, error, ... so write one line and not 50 !!

Comment: @user1069516 Well, yes, write your `$.ajax()` code where `alert()` is being executed in my example. :)